# complex Algebra question

Tags: algebra-precalculus

This question is not related to any assignment and I've already graduated a long time ago. However, this came across in my workplace and I need to solve these four equations:
$$ T_1 = SX^2+GX+C $$
$$ T_2 = SY^2+GY+C $$
$$ T_3 = S(X+a)^2+G(X+a)+C $$
$$ T_4 = S(Y+a)^2+G(Y+a)+C $$
These are the known parameters : $ T_1, T_2, T_3, T_4, Y, a$ 
These are unknown : $X,S,G, \text{and } C$.
I just want to find $X$ by using these equations.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Yeah i solved similar equation, but it was linear not quadratic like these four equations :$$ T_1=GX+C$$ $$ T_2=GY+C$$ $$T_3=G(X+a)+C$$ $$T_4=G(Y+a)+C$$  And I solved this one by using this equation : $$X=\frac{T_1-T_2}{T_4-T_2}*a+Y$$ That's it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, systems of polynomial equations like this can be solved by computing a suitable "Groebner basis". Here is a way to do that using the free software GAP:

```
R := PolynomialRing( Rationals, ["t1","t2","t3","t4","a","s","g","c","y","x"]);
t1:= IndeterminatesOfPolynomialRing(R)[1];
t2:= IndeterminatesOfPolynomialRing(R)[2];
t3:= IndeterminatesOfPolynomialRing(R)[3];
t4:= IndeterminatesOfPolynomialRing(R)[4];
a:= IndeterminatesOfPolynomialRing(R)[5];
s := IndeterminatesOfPolynomialRing(R)[6];
g := IndeterminatesOfPolynomialRing(R)[7];
c := IndeterminatesOfPolynomialRing(R)[8];
y := IndeterminatesOfPolynomialRing(R)[9];
x := IndeterminatesOfPolynomialRing(R)[10];
i1:=s*x^2+g*x+c-t1;
i2:=s*y^2+g*y+c-t2;
i3:=s*(x+a)^2+g*(x+a)+c-t3;
i4:=s*(y+a)^2+g*(y+a)+c-t4;
I := Ideal(R, [i1,i2,i3,i4]);
ord := EliminationOrdering([s,g,c]);
B:=GroebnerBasis(I,ord);
```

It outputs an equation in which $S$, $G$, and $C$ have been eliminated:

```
[ t1*a-t1*y+t1*x-t2*a-t2*y+t2*x+t3*a+t3*y-t3*x-t4*a+t4*y-t4*x, ...]
```

In other words, it gives us an equation:

$$T_1a-T_1Y+T_1X-T_2a-T_2Y+T_2X+T_3a+T_3Y-T_3X-T_4a+T_4Y-T_4X=0$$

which can be solved for $X$:

$$X=\frac{(T_3-T_2)(Y+a)+(T_4-T_1)(Y-a)}{T_1+T_2-T_3-T_4}$$

Comment: sheesh, I need to learn to use CAS's more,  the long way is annoying :).

Answer (score 0):

Start going through and solving for variables and plugging that into the other equations to reduce variables.  I'll start with the first and solve for C:

$$C=T_1 -SX^2+GX$$

Now plug that into the other equations for C to reduce the problem to an system with 3 variables, 3 unknowns:
$$T_2=SY^2+GY+T_1 -SX^2+GX$$
$$T_3=S(X+a)^2 +G(X+a)+T_1 -SX^2+GX$$
$$T_4=S(Y+a)^2 +G(Y+a)+T_1 -SX^2+GX$$
Continue, since the end goal is to get X we'll do that last, so solving for G in the $T_2$ equation, we have
$$G=\frac {T_2-SY^2-T_1+SX^2}{X+Y}$$
Now we plug that into the other two equations,(Factoring the one G to simplify the expression) getting 
$$T_3=S(X+a)^2 +T_1 -SX^2+\frac {T_2-SY^2-T_1+SX^2}{X+Y}(2X+a)$$
$$T_4=S(Y+a)^2 +T_1 -SX^2+\frac {T_2-SY^2-T_1+SX^2}{X+Y}(X+Y+a)$$
Solving for S in the $T_3$ equation,it's a little cleaner to clear out the fractions, so I'll multiply by $X+Y$ to get 
$$T_3(X+Y)=S(X+a)^2(X+Y)  +T_1(X+Y)-SX^2(X+Y)+ (T_2-SY^2-T_1+SX^2)(2X+a)$$
Now we need to multiply out the last part to separate the pars with S and the parts without,and I'll move the $T_1$ term over also
$$T_3(X+Y)-T_1(X+Y)=S(X+a)^2(X+Y)  -SX^2(X+Y)+ 2T_2X-2XSY^2-2XT_1+2SX^3+aT_2-aSY^2-aT_1+aSX^2$$
Factoring out the $S$ and moving the other terms to the other side, we have
 $$T_3(X+Y)-T_1(X+Y)-2T_2X+2XT_1-aT_2+aT_1=S((X+a)^2(X+Y)  -X^2(X+Y)+ -2XY^2+X^3-aY^2+aX^2)$$
So, dividing by the coefficent of S, we have
$$S=\frac {T_3(X+Y)-T_1(X+Y)-2T_2X+2XT_1-aT_2+aT_1} {(X+a)^2(X+Y)  -X^2(X+Y)+ -2XY^2+X^3-aY^2+aX^2}$$
Before plugging that into the $T_4$ equation, I'm going to remove the fractions by multiplying through by $X+Y$ to give us
$$T_4(X+Y)=S(Y+a)^2(X+Y) +T_1(X+Y) -SX^2(X+Y)+(T_2-SY^2-T_1+SX^2)(X+Y+a)$$
Again, I'm going to get the S terms grouped a little more so I don't have to plug in that ugly fraction so much: 
$$T_4(X+Y)=S((Y+a)^2(X+Y)-X^2(X+Y)) +T_1(X+Y) +(T_2-T_1+S(X^2-Y^2))
(X+Y+a)$$

Plugging in that S, we see that we have
$$T_4(X+Y)=\frac {T_3(X+Y)-T_1(X+Y)-2T_2X+2XT_1-aT_2+aT_1} {(X+a)^2(X+Y)  -X^2(X+Y)+ -2XY^2+X^3-aY^2+aX^2}((Y+a)^2(X+Y)-X^2(X+Y)) +T_1(X+Y) +(T_2-T_1+\frac {T_3(X+Y)-T_1(X+Y)-2T_2X+2XT_1-aT_2+aT_1} {(X+a)^2(X+Y)  -X^2(X+Y)+ -2XY^2+X^3-aY^2+aX^2}(X^2-Y^2))
(X+Y+a)$$

Which is ridicuoulsly long of course.  So we will multiply by the denominator of $S$ to clear out the fraction, so multiplying the euqation by $$(X+a)^2(X+Y)  -X^2(X+Y)+ -2XY^2+X^3-aY^2+aX^2$$, we get....I'll now break it up into left hand side (LHS) and right hand side (RHS).  So the LHS is 
$$T_4(X+Y)((X+a)^2(X+Y)  -X^2(X+Y)+ -2XY^2+X^3-aY^2+aX^2)$$
and the RHS is (assuming I haven't misplaced anything in this mess)
$$(T_3(X+Y)-T_1(X+Y)-2T_2X+2XT_1-aT_2+aT_1)((Y+a)^2(X+Y)-X^2(X+Y))+T_1(X+Y)((X+a)^2(X+Y)  -X^2(X+Y)+ -2XY^2+X^3-aY^2+aX^2)+((T_2-T_1)((X+a)^2(X+Y)  -X^2(X+Y)+ -2XY^2+X^3-aY^2+aX^2)+(T_3(X+Y)-T_1(X+Y)-2T_2X+2XT_1-aT_2+aT_1)(X^2-Y^2))(X+Y+a)$$

So, we're finally down to an equation with only X as the unknown.  What's even better is that it appears to be a quartic (Highest power of X is 4), which means there's a formula to solve for it....so all that's left is multiplying out everything,  and combining like terms, then plugging it into the quartic equation.

However, I see someone else gave a CAS solution 10 minutes ago,  and so I'll leave finishing this as an exercise to the student :)

Comment: If the CAS answer is correct, then presumably after multiplying out and collecting like terms, your quartic reduces to a linear equation in $X$. Seems a bit unlikely, though.

Comment: There's a decent chance I made an error along the way, I was calculating on the fly as I typed it in.